# Startx wont start for Centos v6.5

Tags: centos, xorg

I am trying to start startx for gnome but for some reason its not working.. I don't have access to this server since its oversees but I've got root pass and i'm using ssh. I've been trying everything I can find on google for the past 2 day with no luck..what should I do ?

logs

```
http://pastebin.com/qHmU5knZ
http://pastebin.com/grrLN0qX
```

short log

```
Initializing built-in extension COMPOSITE
Initializing built-in extension DAMAGE
Initializing built-in extension MIT-SCREEN-SAVER
Initializing built-in extension DOUBLE-BUFFER
Initializing built-in extension RECORD
Initializing built-in extension DPMS
Initializing built-in extension X-Resource
Initializing built-in extension XVideo
Initializing built-in extension XVideo-MotionCompensation
Initializing built-in extension SELinux
Initializing built-in extension XFree86-VidModeExtension
Initializing built-in extension XFree86-DGA
Initializing built-in extension XFree86-DRI
Initializing built-in extension DRI2
Loading extension GLX
Setting DAC:
00: 00 00 00 00 BF 3F 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
10: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 07 07 C9 FF BF 20 1F 20
20: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 40
30: 00 B0 00 C2 34 14 02 83 00 93 00 77 00 00 00 3A
40: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
OPTION  = 41049120
OPTION2 = 0000B000
CRTCEXT: 10 C8 00 83 00 00
Setting DAC:
00: 00 00 00 00 BF 3F 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
10: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 07 07 C9 FF BF 20 1F 20
20: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 40
30: 00 B0 00 C2 34 14 02 83 00 93 00 77 00 00 00 3A
40: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
OPTION  = 41049120
OPTION2 = 0000B000
CRTCEXT: 10 C8 00 83 00 00
The XKEYBOARD keymap compiler (xkbcomp) reports:
> Warning:          Type "ONE_LEVEL" has 1 levels, but <RALT> has 2 symbols
>                   Ignoring extra symbols
Errors from xkbcomp are not fatal to the X server

waiting for X server to shut down Setting DAC:
00: 03 00 00 00 BF 3F 00 00 FF FF FF 00 00 00 00 00
10: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 07 00 89 00 00 20 11 00
20: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 30 03 14 F1 01 40
30: 02 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
40: 00 00 00 00 11 90 07 00 0C 75 07 00 1F BF 07 40
OPTION  = 40001120
OPTION2 = 0000B000
CRTCEXT: 00 88 00 00 00 00
Server terminated successfully (0). Closing log file.
```

Comment: The progress of startx is logged in "/var/log/Xorg.0.log". If you want to debug what is failing when starting X, check this log file for hints.

Comment: First login as runlevel 3, after that try startx

Comment: @max I checked /etc/inittab and i have tried with id:3:initdefault: and id:5:initdefault: each time rebooted and tried starting with no luck